# Is there any advantage with the "in" keyword on reference types?

Tags: c#, performance, keyword

I am just curious, is there any advantage of using the `in` keyword for a reference type parameter (like `string`)?

Sample:

```
bool IsNice(string greeding)
{
    return greeding.Contains(":-)");
}
```

VS

```
bool IsNice2(in string greeding)
{
    return greeding.Contains(":-)");
}
```

Comment: No; I wouldn't be surprised if there was a slight performance penalty

Comment: The main advantage of `in` is for large value types; the only time I'd expect to see  `in` with a reference type is when it is `in T someValue` for some `T` in a generic `<T>` type/method, and the `T` turns out to be a reference-type sometimes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In performance terms, probably not much. You're adding an extra dereference.

Take the code

```
public class C
{
    public void WithoutIn(string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }

    public void WithIn(in string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

This gets jitted as:

```
C.WithoutIn(System.String)
    L0000: mov ecx, edx
    L0002: call System.Console.WriteLine(System.String)
    L0007: ret

C.WithIn(System.String ByRef)
    L0000: mov ecx, [edx]
    L0002: call System.Console.WriteLine(System.String)
    L0007: ret
```

([SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LghgzgtgPgAgBgARwIwG4CwAoOBmFAJiQGEkBvHJalAuAFiQHUBLYACwHsBXYASQB2ACjTIIASio1K2GnJSoAnEIlZZNAL5Tq22ikasOgoSwEKxk9dRnyaaZat1bsGoA==)).

The only difference is `mov ecx, [edx]` rather than `mov ecx edx`. I would imagine this dereference would slow things down slightly, but not by any observable amount.

In practical terms, it means you cannot do this:

```
public void M(in string s)
{
    s = "foo"; // CS8331: Cannot assign to variable 'in string' because it is a readonly variable
}
```

`in` was added to the language to enhance support for passing structs by reference. I'd call into question any code which used it with a reference type: I'd assume that it came about as the result of a value type being later changed into a reference type, and not because of some deliberate decision.

Comment: Thanks to all answers, I mark this as solution for showing and explaining the CIL and pointing out that, against most expectations, the IN keyword on reference types makes it potentially SLOWER!

Comment: @Marc Thanks! Note that that's assembly, not CIL.

Answer (score 2):

From "[In Parameters in C# 7.2 – Read-only References](https://dailydotnettips.com/in-parameters-in-c-7-2-read-only-references/)":

> In parameters in C# are like ref parameter only, except they are read-only inside the method.  And, they can’t be modified further. You can only refer them.

So read only?

Comment: Note that this just means that you can't assign to the reference - you can mutate it.

Comment: @canton7 Aren't string immutable?

Comment: @UweKeim Strings are, but other reference types might not be. The OP's question was about all reference types, with `string` being just an example

Comment: It's a read-only ref with some extra behavior for value types. It's not really going to make a difference in this case.

Comment: Perhaps not the best ref type choice for the question.

Comment: If a value-type parameter has an `in` qualifier, what will the compiler do with instance methods and properties: (1) disallow their use; (2) allow them, and pass a copy of the structure, or (3) allow them, and pass the actual structure?

Comment: @supercat that's its own question. It copies the struct anyway, unless the struct is marked `readonly`

Comment: @canton7: If the `in` property affects the behavior of struct methods and properties, that would be an advantage in the cases where the effects are desirable, tying in with the original question.  A `ref` parameter won't copy the struct at all.  A non-qualified parameter will copy it once on entry.  I think a `readonly` parameter would copy it once on entry, and again on any call to a property getter.

Answer (score 0):

The two behave differently.

In the second example any changes made to the variable you pass by reference will be observed by the method.

In the first case you're not passing in a variable, you're just passing in a value. If you got that value by getting the value of a variable, then any changes to that variable afterwards won't be observed.

It's going to be rather difficult for the variable to change after the initial call to the method, so I wouldn't expect it to matter in practice very often, but it's possible.